# How to call multiple Javascript function using onclientclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a asp button code is:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="Submit" onclick="btn_click"   

onclientclick= "javascript:returnisvalid
(document.getelementbyid
('*somevalue*'));" />
```

What I need is now I need to call another function to prevent double clicking of the button which I created is

```
Function disablesave(savebutton){
Savebutton.disabled=true;
Savebutton.value=true;

}
```

How can I validate the form and call this function on single onclientclick? Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: I tried this onclientclick=return (fun1() && fun2() ); now onclick event is not firing

Answer (score 1):

You can call multiple functions by separate them with semicolon `;`, or comma `,`

```
onclientclick="function1(); function2();"
```

You can also call them connected with logical operations if you need to validate all of them, for example:

```
onclientclick="return (function1() && function2());"
```

or even as

```
onclientclick="function1(); return function2();"
```

alternative to avoid double submissions and only with javascript used you can go to the `form` and add your logic there using the `onsubmit`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return disableForm(this);">
```

Then on the javascript function `disableForm()` add your logic procedures.